# Xen: some logical volumes are missing after dist-upgrade vrom Debian 10 to 12 and after reboot

Tags: lvm, xen

I updated my Debian Xen Server from 10 to 11 and then without reboot to Debian 12, then I rebooted the server and now only some VMs started.

vm06 is running fine while vm04 is not (and some more, but here i redacted them from this question for readability)

In the folder /dev/vg0 are only some of the vlumes linked now:

```
# ll /dev/vg0/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Aug 20 17:04 backup -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Aug 20 17:04 root -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Aug 20 17:04 vm06.docker-disk -> ../dm-10
```

```
# lvs
  LV                              VG  Attr       LSize    Pool Origin                 Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  backup                          vg0 -wi-ao----    2,01t                                                                    
  root                            vg0 -wi-ao----   10,00g                                                                    
  vm04.matrix-disk                vg0 owi-i-s---  130,00g                         
  vm06.docker-disk                vg0 owi-a-s---  610,00g
```

If I use `lvdisplay`, the missing volume vm04-matrix is still included like:

```
# lvdisplay|grep Path|grep -v swap
  LV Path                /dev/vg0/root
  LV Path                /dev/vg0/backup
  LV Path                /dev/vg0/vm06.docker-disk
  LV Path                /dev/vg0/vm04.matrix-disk
```

```
lvdisplay|awk  '/LV Name/{n=$3} /Block device/{d=$3; sub(".*:","dm-",d); print d,n;}'
```

shows, that the matrix disk is present at `/dev/dm-25`

```
# cat /etc/lvm/backup/vg0

...

vg0 {
    id = "Cfe7Ii-rZBl-mEnH-tk5Z-q9WW-UyTk-3WstVn"
    seqno = 29269
    format = "lvm2"         # informational
    status = ["RESIZEABLE", "READ", "WRITE"]
    flags = []
    extent_size = 8192      # 4 Megabytes
    max_lv = 0
    max_pv = 0
    metadata_copies = 0

    physical_volumes {

        pv0 {
            id = "KlmZUe-3FiK-VbBZ-R962-219A-GGAU-I3a5Nl"
            device = "/dev/md1" # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = []
            dev_size = 15626736256  # 7,27677 Terabytes
            pe_start = 2048
            pe_count = 1907560  # 7,27676 Terabytes
        }
    }

    logical_volumes {

        ...

        vm06.docker-disk {
            id = "y3CSuy-z4gU-72Bd-678E-sYTi-Lkmi-dwAkgT"
            status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
            flags = []
            creation_time = 1584654364  # 2020-03-19 22:46:04 +0100
            creation_host = "dom0-eclabs"
            segment_count = 3

            segment1 {
                start_extent = 0
                extent_count = 97280    # 380 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv0", 263936
                ]
            }
            segment2 {
                start_extent = 97280
                extent_count = 7680 # 30 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv0", 422912
                ]
            }
            segment3 {
                start_extent = 104960
                extent_count = 51200    # 200 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv0", 1050889
                ]
            }
        }

        ...
        
        vm04.matrix-disk {
            id = "Tak3Zq-3dUU-SAJl-Hd5h-weTM-cHMR-qgWXeI"
            status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
            flags = []
            creation_time = 1584774051  # 2020-03-21 08:00:51 +0100
            creation_host = "dom0-eclabs"
            segment_count = 2

            segment1 {
                start_extent = 0
                extent_count = 25600    # 100 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv0", 531968
                ]
            }
            segment2 {
                start_extent = 25600
                extent_count = 7680 # 30 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv0", 1002249
                ]
            }
        }

    }
}
```

dmsetup still lists the disk:

```
 # dmsetup info|grep matrix 
Name:              vg0-vm04.matrix--disk
```

But it doesn't seem to be linked in /dev/dm-X:

```
# for i in /dev/dm-*; do echo $i; dmsetup info $i; done|grep matrix
```

(This shows nothing).

I already did `pvcreate –restorefile lvm_backup_datei –uuid <uuid> <partition>` in recovery mode like explained [here](https://docs.hetzner.com/de/robot/dedicated-server/troubleshooting/recovery-of-lvm-volumes/) and rebooted, but still the same problem.

I noticed, that **in the recovery system all lvm partitions were there** with `lsblk` and under `/dev/mapper/...` (the rescue system uses kernel 6.4.7) but after a reboot into the system, again only those few are visible:

```
├─sdb2                                          8:18   0   7,3T  0 part  
│ └─md1                                         9:1    0   7,3T  0 raid1 
│   ├─vg0-root                                253:0    0    10G  0 lvm   /
│   ├─vg0-swap                                253:1    0     4G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
│   ├─vg0-backup                              253:2    0     2T  0 lvm   /backup   
│   ├─vg0-vm06.docker--swap                   253:8    0     8G  0 lvm   
│   ├─vg0-vm06.docker--disk-real              253:9    0   610G  0 lvm   
│   │ ├─vg0-vm06.docker--disk                 253:10   0   610G  0 lvm   
│   │ └─vg0-snap--tmp--vm06.docker--disk      253:12   0   610G  0 lvm   
│   ├─vg0-snap--tmp--vm06.docker--disk-cow    253:11   0    16G  0 lvm   
│   │ └─vg0-snap--tmp--vm06.docker--disk      253:12   0   610G  0 lvm
```

### update:

I managed to mount the missing volumes in rescue mode into a backup partition and backup all needed data, so I can create a new volume, reinstall and feed in the backed up database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you manually call

```
lvchange -a y /dev/vg0
```

this will reinstate all volumes.

Also you have to notice, that thekernel is updated to `/boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-11-amd64` which has to be updated in the /etc/xen/x.conf files

also did the Network-device inside the vms change from former `eth0` to `enX0`which hadto be adapted in each VMs network settings